# Spring Security cache headers are incomplete

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

Using Spring Security default configurations under Spring Boot (1.3.0.M5 with spring-boot-starter-web), the Cache-Control and Pragma headers are included but values differ from docs.

Received:

```
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires: 0
Pragma:
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html specify:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Any obvious reason why this should be?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: I've just tried this with [spring-boot-sample-web-secure in the 1.2.x branch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.2.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure) and the three headers are as documented. Perhaps you can provide a sample that exhibits the unwanted behaviour?